# Bound on Second Moment of Solution of Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expected-value, stochastic-differential-equations

**Question**

Consider the following stochastic differential equation, given as an equivalent stochastic integral equation, where the multidimensional integrals are to be read componentwise:

\begin{equation}
 S_t = x_0 + \int_{0}^{t} \mu(S_t) ds + \int_{0}^{t} \sigma (S_t) dB_s.
\end{equation}

Under our assumptions, it is the case that an (up to indistinguishability) unique solution process

$$ S^{(x_0, \theta_{\sigma}, \theta_{\mu})} :[0,T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d, \quad (t, \omega) \mapsto S_t(\omega),$$

for this equation exists (to see this, consider for example Theorem 8.3. in *Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus* from Le Gall).

I am now looking for upper bounds $L(x_0, \theta_{\sigma}, \theta_{\mu}, t) \in [0, \infty)$ of the second moment expression such that
$$ \mathbb{E}[\lVert S^{(x_0, \theta_{\sigma}, \theta_{\mu})}_t \rVert^2  ] \leq  L(x_0, \theta_{\sigma}, \theta_{\mu}, t).$$

Does such a bound $L(x_0, \theta_{\sigma}, \theta_{\mu}, t)$ always exist? What can one say about it and how does it depend on $(x_0, \theta_{\sigma}, \theta_{\mu}, t)$?

I am stuck and I would be extremely grateful for any advice!

**Technical Framework**

- Let $T \in (0, \infty)$ be fixed.
- Let $d \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ be fixed.
- Let $$(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, (\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,T]},
     \mathbb{P})$$ be a complete probability space with a complete,
  right-continuous filtration $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$.
- Let $$B : [0,T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d, \quad
     (t,\omega) \mapsto B_t(\omega)$$ be a standard $d$-dimensional
  $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$-adapted Brownian motion on
  $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that, for every pair $(t,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2$
  with $0 \leq t < s$, the random variable $B_s-B_t$ is independent of
  $\mathcal{G}_t$.
- Let  \begin{align}  &\sigma: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d
     \times d}, \\  &\mu: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d},
      \end{align}  be affine linear transformations, i.e. let there be matrices
  $(A^{(\sigma)}_1,...,A^{(\sigma)}_d, \bar{A}^{(\sigma)}):= \theta_{\sigma} \in
     (\mathbb{R}^{d \times d})^{d+1}$ such that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$,
  \begin{equation}  \sigma(x) = ( A^{(\sigma)}_1 x \mid ... \mid
     A^{(\sigma)}_d x) + \bar{A}^{(\sigma)},  \end{equation}  where
  $A^{(\sigma)}_i x$ describes the $i$-th column of the matrix
  $\sigma(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, and let there be a matrix-vector pair $(A^{(\mu)}, \bar{a}^{(\mu)}) := \theta_{\mu}
     \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} \times \mathbb{R}^d$ 
  such that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$,   \begin{equation}  \mu (x) =
     A^{(\mu)}x + \bar{a}^{(\mu)}. \end{equation} 
  Note, that this implies, that $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are globally Lipschitz.
- Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be fixed.

Comment: Maybe Minkowski's integral inequality (with possibly Jensen's inequ) to control the drift, and the Ito isometry to control the Brownian term. Then apply Gronwall's inequality.

Comment: For SDEs with Lipschitz continuous coefficients such $L^2$ estimates are well-known, typically you get them while constructing the solution to the SDE; see e.g. Theorem 19.13 or Theorem 19.28 in the book by Schilling & Partzsch (2nd edition). They do not give an explicit expression for the constant but you can see from the proof (see also the proof of the previous result) that the constant $L$ is of the form $$L = c_1 (1+x_0^2) \exp(c_2 K^2 t)$$ where $K$ is the Lipschitz constant of the drift and diffusion coefficient and $c_1,c_2$ are some uniform constants.